# How does CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync actually work behind the scenes?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

Does it download all of the binaries or only a part of it in order to evaluate if the binaries are of new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it evaluates the XAP, which contains all binaries, but if the version on the XAP hasn't changed it doesn't see any changes.

Here is a bit more light on that method (lifted from [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/vblasberg/archive/2010/06/12/silverlight-oob-checkanddownloadupdateasync.aspx) but pasted for historical reasons):

> Features:
>
> • Detect network connectivity (and sometimes it fails miserably…)
>
> • Connect to the original authorized URL that it was installed from
>
> • Download the new XAP file and compare the current version against the downloaded version from the manifest
>
> • Detect the current Silverlight version vs. the new version’s Silverlight version
>
> • If a failure occurs, failure exception types are provided for recovery such as “PlatformNotSupportedException”
>
> Limitations:
>
> • Can’t interrupted the request.  So when it times out, we wait for it.
>
> • Can’t download the update and make it optional to install and replace the currently running XAP.  A flag to just detect a newer version would be better.  This would allow the UI to show the current version and available update version.
>
> • Returns a false for the “UpdateAvailable” property for several reasons such as the new XAP is not signed, is a newer Silverlight Version, or various other errors.  We must then look at *ALL* of the possible error class types placed in the error collection.  A bunch of try-catches are therefore necessary.  The try-catches do the job as long as we have every possible error type in a catch.  An enum for the actual error reason may be better.
>
> • Can’t revert to a previous stable version and have it install over a newer bad version.  It makes sense, but real development teams have recovery plans when updating production versions.

Comment: Ok, if I understand it correctly the "whole"-XAP is downloaded and then the version are checked on the client, is that correct?